# BoxDecorations overlap eachother

Tags: flutter

I'm using this snippet to display a clickable button:

```
InkWell(customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
        onTap: ()=>{},
        child: Ink(
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
             shape: BoxShape.circle,
             image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      image: NetworkImage("https://i.imgur.com/TpQD6PA_d.webp"))),
                ),
              )
```

and it displays fine:

[image: works fine]

but if I wrap the Inkwell in a Container with a background, the background *overlaps*

```
Container( // ⬅ this with this ⬇
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),
        child: InkWell(
          customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
          onTap: ()=>{},
          child: Ink(
            width: 80,
            height: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, image: NetworkImage("https://i.imgur.com/TpQD6PA_d.webp"))),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

and it looks like this:

[image: no good]

I can't put the background into the inkwell as this is just a simplified example. In my actual app, the background is a standard widget I use as a generic list-item background.

Comment: You can use Stack for this usecase

Answer (score 0):

Because the `Container` has a fixed size of 80x80. You can use this way:

```
Container(
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),
  child: SizedBox(
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    child: InkWell(
      customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
      onTap: () => {},
      child: Ink(
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            image: NetworkImage("https://i.imgur.com/TpQD6PA_d.webp"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This solution wouldn't work for me as I need to use the container as a generic background for a lot of stuff. It won't necessarily know what its children's sizes are

Comment: You need to provide more code about the background .

Comment: I just tried your solution in my app and it doesn't work, can you attach a screen for how it looks for you?